# Wrapping filter formula into Array Formula to avoid dragging formula down sheet while also using named ranges

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, array-formulas

Original formula:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FILTER(typeOfFund, listOfFunds = $K5), 1, 1)
```

The filter function by itself works (without the ArrayFormula) and if I'm only testing it with "K5" (instead of a range of multiple cells). However, it only outputs into the one cell the formula is located in. So I have to drag down the formula which slows down performance.

So I try to wrap it into an array formula and change the "K5" to a range to a longer range such as K5:K6

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(typeOfFund, listOfFunds = $K5:K6))
```

I also made sure to delete values down the range to avoid the "this formula will overwrite other cells" error.

[image]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: FILTER will not work in an Arrayformula.  This is by design.  You may be able to achieve the same result however if you share a bit more about those named ranges and what the actual goal is.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by the comments and requests of "player0" and "MattKing," it's difficult (and often impossible) to suggest working formulas without seeing the spreadsheet and data in context. However, here is a stab in the dark at what you may actually need.

Try clearing M5:M and then place the following formula in M5:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(K5:K,{listOfFunds,typeOfFund},2,FALSE)))`

This formula is based on the assumption  that the named ranges listOfFunds and typeOfFund run vertically parallel to one another and have the same starting point and number of rows in each.

If the Force Be With You, it may work.

If not, do share a link to your spreadsheet (or to a copy of it).